# How to render .rst files in a markdown or html format?

Tags: django, documentation

In many django projects, in the docs directory I can see `*.rst` files:

Is there a standard, simple, or common way of rendering and displaying these, instead of viewing their contents as plain text?

Is it possible to generate HTML from the `.rst` files?

Comment: Can you please edit the description to expand on the "without using a text editor of course"? That would seem to be a good way, and your reasons for rejecting it aren't clear.

Comment: Edits have been made to try to salvage this question from being opinion-based. Is there a process for removing the `opinion-based` flag now?

Answer (score 40):

`.rst` files are [ReStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) format.  They look like text files, but can be rendered into HTML with the Python [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) package.

Comment: any steps of how to do that?

Comment: The docutils package installs a program called `rst2html.py`. Use that.

Comment: @liang `rst2html.py FOO.rst > FOO.html`

Comment: I prefer this approach because it doesn't launch any web servers. I redirect output to `w3m` like: `rst2html.py somefile.rst | w3m -T text/html`.

Answer (score 25):

As zjk says, you can use restview:

> restview is available from the Python Package Index: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/restview. You can also pip install restview.

Here is what I did to test it out using a virtual environment:

```
mkdir restview
cd restview/
virtualenv-2.7 venv   # The second system I used just used 'virtualenv venv'
./venv/bin/pip install restview
./venv/bin/restview ~/path/MANUAL.rst
```

This launched a web server and opened the documentation page in my browser.

Note: I only used virtualenv because I don't like installing things globally.  It may be overkill for many others, but I also have better luck with these one-off environemnets.  When I tried `pip install restview` on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM it failed, whereas the approach above worked like a charm for me on that system as well as this one.

Comment: oh, I didn't know I can use virtualenv this way too. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Try [restview](http://mg.pov.lt/restview/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.